# Facebook App To Post to Multiple Pages

Tags: facebook

Now before I ask, I'm not looking to post the same message to multiple pages here. That would be SPAM.

What we have done is create some code and a Facebook app that allows us to post to a Facebook page based on content in a database. However, we're having to create a separate app for each page we want to post to.

I was wondering if it was possible to get an Auth token for each page and then use the same app to post to individual pages...?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use the same App. Just generate a Page Token per Page.